# Subform vs. Textboxes for a Many Relationship

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently in the process of creating an Access 2013 DB. The DB currently has two tables [Personal Information] and [Position Applied For], which is in a one to many relationship. With one person applying to many jobs. The problem that I am having with this database, is that within the form in order to successfully show the [Position Applied For] table it has to be in a subform. The user that I am building this DB for prefers textboxes instead. Is it possible to link textboxes to individual records/fields within the [Position Applied For] table since it is the many in the relationship? I have created the form but the textboxes are only linking to the first position the person applies for, I would like to show up to four position's the person applies for.

[Position Applied For] Fields:

1. ID (PK)
2. Personal ID (FK)
3. List item
4. Resume Source Internal
5. Personal Reference Name
6. Job Board
7. Position Applied For
8. Date of Submission

Comment: Yes, you need to add something in the source like a SQL statement based on others, or use the D functions of Access, so I generally have a hidden key, say USER_ID, then txtFirstName has the source, "Dlookup("FirstName","tbl_Users","User_ID=" & me.txtUserID.value.   Can you not style the subform to be of textbox appearance single form?

Comment: What are the proper steps styling the subform to be of textbox appearance? Sorry, I forgot to include the two ID fields within the table.

Comment: What does "prefers textboxes instead" mean? A subform has textboxes on it.

Comment: The user prefers the lookup textboxes similar if the table was not in a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even start going down this road.

For the "many" part you need some sort of list. If it's read-only, a listbox does the job, but for editing and creating records, a subform with `Default View = Continuous Form` is the way to go.

And as Brad wrote, it can have lots of textboxes. :)
One per column * number of records.